# Can anyone tell me the issue with my logic for this HackerRank question? (Repeated String, Link in Description)

Tags: python

This code keeps messing up on weird edge cases but I don't see how it's wrong.  It works for about half the cases given on the site, but will be off by 2 for some of the larger cases.  The basic logic of the code is (1) Find the number of a's in a single instance of the string (2) Multiply that number by the number of times the string goes into n (3) Get the number of a's in the last occurrence of the string that did not fit into n.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/repeated-string/problem

```
#/bin/python3
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

#Complete the repeatedString function below.
def repeatedString(s, n):
    total_a = 0
    #Get number of a's in one instance of the string
    string_a = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == 'a':
            string_a += 1
    
    #Get number of times whole string occurs and multiply with a's in single string
    total_a = string_a * n//len(s)

    #Get remainder a's
    chars_left = n%len(s)
    s2 = s[:chars_left]
    for i in range(len(s2)):
        if s2[i] == 'a':
            total_a += 1

    return total_a



if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    s = input()

    n = int(input())

    result = repeatedString(s, n)

    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: Do you know the input/ouptut values for those larger test cases? Please share if you have them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `total_a = string_a * n//len(s)` 
replace with `total_a = string_a * (n//len(s))`.
In your case * is evaluating first

**Python Operators Precedence:
*   /   %   //   + -**

More clean code:

```
def repeatedString(s, n):
    return s.count('a') * (n//len(s)) + s[:n%len(s)].count('a')
```